# IIS Sites not created in all servers in Farm SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, iis

I have SharePoint 2013 Farm with 2 WFE and 3 App Server:

I have 3 Web Applications aside from Central Admin.

In IIS i have all sites created properly except on WFE2.

I only see 2 Web Applications in IIS.

I can see all other IIS displaying properly in rest of the servers.

How can i make this missing site available in IIS and what would be the root cause of this issue?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

couple of things to make sure.

- Make sure "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application" service is running on the WFE2.
- Make Sure SharePoint Admin and timer Service running on WFE2.
- Sometime Reboot help.

If still having issue, please check the logs / Event log and share if you see any error.

Comment: But can i restore the Site into WFE2 from other servers. Or can we sync IIS sites that are created in another server?

Comment: i dont think it is good idea to copy the IIS site....make sure the above services then you can recreate the web application and it will provision on all servers...also check this http://www.sharepointgeoff.com/a-solution-to-web-applications-not-being-provisioned-on-the-sharepoint-web-front-end-servers/